# finding the size of a template in c++ for a class with default arguments

Tags: c++, size, memory-alignment

My doubt regarding this is why calculating the size of b gives output as 8 bytes (the size of int on my machine is 4 bytes). Shouldn't it be 4 (for int) + 1 (for char; set as default)? Moreover what is the criteria for determining size when I am specifying multiple default arguments in template declaration?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T, class U = char> class A
{
public:
    T x;
    U y;
};
int main()
{
    A<char> a;
    A<int> b;
    cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
 2
 8
```

Comment: The templating is completely irrelevant. Please remove that from your example and the question title.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to hardware limitations an object of size N > 1 may have to be placed at a memory address that is a multiple of some address step size A that depends on N, but that is typically 2, 4, 8 or 16. This is called **alignment**. Since a value can always be reconstituted from its individual bytes, which can be accessed at any address, this is only a matter of efficiency, but the efficiency loss of bad alignment, if such were supported, can be huge.

To support alignment, the compiler pads structs so that in a sequence of such structs, such as in an array, each one will be acceptably aligned provided the first one is.

In your case the struct with two `char` values (bytes) is not padded, since these values can be efficiently accessed at any address. But the struct with an `int` is padded, to ensure that that `int` will always end up at acceptable alignment. In particular in an array of such structs.

---

Re the final question

> **”** Moreover what is the criteria for determining size when I am specifying multiple default arguments in template declaration?

… the defaulting of template arguments is completely irrelevant wrt. size.

Comment: thanks...i came across the concept of memory alignment but wasn't sure that it applied to all composite data types...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is memory alignment.

For A a, a has two members with type of char, so the size is 1 + 1 = 2, but for A b, b has two members, one with type of char, the other with type of int, the size is not simply 1 + 4 = 5, because of the memory alignment, the size is (1 + 3) + 4, 3 is for alignment. The following picture shows the alignment.

[image: Memory alignment]

Memory alignment could improve the memory accessing performance.In C++, the alignment length usually is the longest size of the element inside of a class or a struct. In your example, the alignment length is sizeof(int) = 4, but in the next example:

```
class E
{
     double x;
     int    Y;
     char   Z;
};
```

Since the longest length is sizeof(double) = 8, so the sizeof(E) would be 8 + (4 + 1 + 3) = 16

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the subsequent example...they cleared my doubt!

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept of data alignment and padding. For detail : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/